# Is it common for IPad 5x operating system to incorrectly rendor webpage JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

So, I have the below script which is also located at http://jsbin.com/asihoh/1/ (run version) and http://jsbin.com/asihoh/1/edit (edit version).  All it does is open an jQueryUI dialog which has a TinyMCE window and a fineupload upload widget.  Works great on Windows PC running FF, IE, and Chrome.  Then I try it on my IPad2 (5.x operating system), but the toolbar images on the TinyMCE editor don't show up, but when their should be location is clicked, they magically appear.  If I remove the fineuploader or sortfixedtable plugins, the toolbar appears as it should with the IPad.

So then, I read a post which says IPad 6.x operating system has debug capability, and I upgrade my firmware so I may debug my bugs, but then the IPad renders the script as it should.

Is it common for IPad 5x operating system to incorrectly rendor webpage JavaScript?  Any suggestions why it was not showing the TinyMCE toolbar icons?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/plugins/sortfixedtable/jquery.sortfixedtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="lib/plugins/fineuploader-3.5/fineuploader-3.5.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {

                $("#myDialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    modal       : true,
                    open        : function() {$('#list').sortfixedtable();}
                });    
                $(".compose").click(function(){$("#myDialog").dialog("open");});

                tinymce.init({
                    //Used for compose message
                    selector: "#tinymce",
                    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | bullist numlist | addLabel",
                    menubar: false,
                    statusbar: false,
                    setup : function(ed) {
                        ed.addButton('addLabel', {
                            title : 'Add Label',
                            image : 'lib/stdimages/icon-16/checkin.png',
                            onclick : function() {alert('click');}
                        });
                    }
                });

                var fineuploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({button: document.getElementById('fineuploader')});
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="compose green wide">COMPOSE</a>

        <div id="myDialog" title="Title">
            <table id="list">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><a href="javascript:void(0)">xxx</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <div id="fineuploader"></div>
            <form><textarea id="tinymce"></textarea></form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, Webkit in general, and especially iPad Safari, have many graphical glitches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the iOS operating system, but with WebKit's rendering engine. Here's the [iOS 6 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/) which has a section on WebKit changes.

Javascript rendering issues are very common.

I also saw this post with a [similar issue](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=24950). Maybe quotes around your parameters may help.

Comment: Thanks Harry,  I will add quotes just in case.  Any thoughts how I can test it with an older WebKit version now that my IPad has been upgraded?